# Why doesn't my image show up in this CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, grid, styling

So I am pretty new to coding and I am trying to create a login page for my React App. And I need to place an image on the left, an image on the right and a Login Card component in the center. And also, how do I make it so that in the mobile view theres, no white space, despite trying to makeing all width and height 100%

```
return (
<>
<Grid
                container
                spacing={0}
                direction="column"
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="center"
                sx={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
>
<Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Stack alignItems="left">
                        <div
                            style={{
                                height: "100%",
                                width: "100vw",
                                backgroundImage: `url("${LEFT _imageT}")`,
                                backgroundSize: "20%",
                                backgroundPosition: "left",
                                backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                                backgroundColor: "#022445",
                                position: "absolute",
                                zIndex: -1,
                                left: 0,
                                bottom: 0,
                            }}
                        ></div>
                    </Stack>
                    <div>
                        <Stack alignItems="center">
                            <Card
                                style={{
                                    width: "40vw",
                                    height: "100%",
                                    marginTop: "150px",
                                    backgroundColor: "#00264a",
                                    boxShadow: "0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)",
                                }}
                            >
<CardComponent></CardComponent>

<div
                        style={{
                            height: "100%",
                            width: "100vw",
                            backgroundImage: `url("${Right_imageT}")`,
                            backgroundSize: "20%",
                            backgroundPosition: "right",
                            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                            backgroundColor: "#022445",
                            position: "absolute",
                            zIndex: -1,
                            right: 10,                  top: 0,
                        }}
                    ></div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>


</>
)
```

I was expecting a page that has my left picture on the left, my right picture on the right and my card component in the middle.
I have tried putting everything in a parent container making the card component and either the left or the right "position: relative" and the remain left/right image: position: absolute:" I also have tried to Grid/ Flexbox, I also have tried playing with the Z-index, of making all of them the same.
But what actually happened is that I only see either my card component with the left image OR my card component with the right image.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!